# How to prove the "damage lemma" for gentle measurements?

Tags: measurement, quantum-operation, weak-measurement

Let $\rho$ be a mixed state. For all $i \in [m]$, let $S_i$ be quantum operation, which is a two-outcome POVM measurement, and "accept" a state $\sigma$ with probability $tr(S_i(\sigma))$ and yields the post-measurement state $\frac{S_i(\sigma)}{tr(S_i(\sigma))}$ when it does. Suppose that for all $i \in [m]$ we have:

$||\frac{S_i(\rho)}{tr(S_i(\rho))} - \rho||_{tr} \le \epsilon_i$.

Let $p_i = tr(S_i(\rho))$ be the probability that $S_i$ accepts the "ideal" state $\rho$, and let

$q_i = \frac{tr(S_i(...S_1(\rho)))}{tr(S_{i-1}(...S_1(\rho)))}$

be the probability that $S_i$ accepts the state that it actually receives, if $S_1,...,S_{i-1}$ are first applied to $\rho$ and if we condition on their accepting. Given any subset $T \subseteq [m]$, let

$p_T = \Pi_{i\in T} p_i, q_T = \Pi_{i\in T} q_i$.

Then for all $T$,

$|p_T-q_T| \le \frac{\epsilon_1 + ... + \epsilon_m}{q_{[m]\backslash T}}$,

Also,

$||\frac{S_m(...S_1(\rho))}{tr(S_m(...S_1(\rho)))} - \rho||_{tr} \le \frac{2}{q_{[m]}}(\epsilon_1 + ... + \epsilon_m)$

**My question is how to prove this lemma17 in the paper** [Gentle measurement of quantum states and differential privacy](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.08747)

The original proof in this paper seems a bit strange, and I don't know whether his proof is correct. I will be appreciated if someone could give me some advice or insight about this lemma.

Comment: what are you saying is "strange" about the proof exactly? Why shouldn't it be correct?